# Re-enable buttons in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Below is my code for buttons the problem I facing is that once button is clicked it wont work again after click of next button. I want to enable the previous clicked button. I hope an expert can help me here.

```
pages.gotoAndStop("home");

// list of button instance names

var buttonsss:Array = [home, menudown.about, menudown.portfolio, menudown.clients, menudown.pricing, menudown.contact];


for each ( var mc:MovieClip in buttonsss)
{
mc.buttonMode = true;
mc.mouseChildren = false;
mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onClick, false, 0, true);
mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, rolloverEffect, false, 0, true);
mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, rolloutEffect, false, 0, true);
    }

function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{

pages.gotoAndStop(e.target.name);
TweenLite.to(e.currentTarget,2,{tint:0xFF0000, ease:Strong.easeOut});
var myTween:Tween = new Tween(pages, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 0, 1, 2, true);       
e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, rolloutEffect);//disable the roll out effect
e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onClick);//disable the roll out effect
e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, rolloverEffect);//disable the roll out effect

}

function rolloverEffect(e:MouseEvent):void{

TweenLite.to(e.currentTarget,2,{tint:0x000000, ease:Strong.easeOut});

}
function rolloutEffect(e:MouseEvent):void{

//should change tint to null just when its enabled, but its changing always (enabled or disabled)
TweenLite.to(e.currentTarget,2,{tint:null , ease:Strong.easeOut});

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a variable called `focusedButton`. Then, in your onClick function do something like this:

```
if ( focusedButton !== null ) {             
    // all the code to re-enable the previous button
    // ie add the listeners and tween alpha             
}

// be sure to store a reference to the new focused button:
focusedButton = e.currentTarget;
```

Then go on with the code for disabling the new button....

EDIT - I saw your comment requesting more code. I'm tempted to let you figure it out yourself since I think I've given you everything you need, but since I don't know what your experience is, I'll take you a bit further. I hope this helps:

```
// put this at the top of your file:
var focusedButton:MovieClip = null;

// an updated onClick function ( untested )
function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{   
    if ( focusedButton !== null ) {             
        // just guessing your unfocus tint:
        TweenLite.to(focusedButton, 2, { tint:0xFFFFFF, ease:Strong.easeOut, onComplete:function():void {
            // remove tint here
        }});
        focusedButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, rolloutEffect);//enable the roll out effect
        focusedButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onClick);//enable the roll out effect
        focusedButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, rolloverEffect);//enable the roll out effect         
    }

    // keep reference to the new button
    focusedButton = MovieClip(e.currentTarget);

    // now disable the new button etc:
    pages.gotoAndStop(e.target.name);
    TweenLite.to(e.currentTarget,2,{tint:0xFF0000, ease:Strong.easeOut});
    var myTween:Tween = new Tween(pages, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 0, 1, 2, true);       
    e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, rolloutEffect);//disable the roll out effect
    e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onClick);//disable the roll out effect
    e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, rolloverEffect);//disable the roll out effect
}
```

Comment: Can you please re-write my code with focusedbutton function you said.

Comment: Thank you Sir , I am getting this error Scene 2, Layer 'actions', 
Frame 2, Line 66 1118: Implicit coercion of a value with static type Object to a possibly unrelated type flash.display:MovieClip.  

here is line 66
     focusedButton = e.currentTarget;

Comment: Which line of code does that refer to? Could it be the reference to e.currentTarget? Try casting it to a MovieClip or Sprite ( whatever it is ) with `MovieClip(e.currentTarget)`

Comment: I also noticed that I made a mistake when tweening the previous button. It should also refer to `focusedButton`, not `e.currentTarget`. I'll fix the code above.

Comment: Just need 1 more help the clicked button remains red after other option being clicked. I want it to be null tint. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure of how your tint is being applied, but you could try adding a `onComplete` handler to your tween, and remove the tint there. I'll add the code in the main answer.

Comment: I hope my answers have helped you. If so, please consider accepting my answer. Good luck.

Comment: I tried something else and that worked. Thanks alot for your help your answer is perfect and helped alot for my project.

Comment: Hi @Ali R. I'm glad that I could help you. I notice that you are a new user on Stack Overflow, so I thought I'd mention to you that it is customary for the person who asked a question to select one answer as being the "correct" answer. This lets people know that the answer is good, and rewards the answerer with "reputation" points, which are like currency on Stack Overflow. If my answer was useful to you, I'd really appreciate the points. Thanks.

Comment: Yes I am new to Stack Overflow and to AS3.0 . I have clicked a right button to show that your answer is very much useful for newbies. Hope this will get you a point. Wish you could help me again on any other problem so you get some more points.

Comment: can you help me on this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189915/flash-as3-fadein-fadeout-xml-slideshow