# flash as3 Fadein fadeout xml slideshow

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, slideshow, flash-cs5

I am new to as3.0 and want to complete my project.

I am using the below code for my xml slideshow but I want the pictures to fade into each other it should never fade to complete white. Hope any expert can help me.

```
import gs.*;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.StageAlign;
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
import flash.events.Event;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;

stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
//hides the description box until the image is loaded
//hides the image until it is loaded

theImage.alpha=0;
loadingBar.visible = false;

//variables to hold the final coordinates of the image tween
var finalX:Number;
var finalY:Number;

//variable to hold the number of images in the XML
var listLength:Number;

//keeps track of what image should be displayed
var currPainting:Number=0;

//arrays to hold the contents of the XML, using this to allow
//for the random order of the images
var imageArray:Array = new Array();


//Loader event for the XML
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);

var xml:XML;

loader.load(new URLRequest("galleries/xml/maingallery.xml"));

function onLoaded(e:Event):void {
//load XML
xml=new XML(e.target.data);
var il:XMLList=xml.images;
listLength=il.length();

populateArray();
}

function populateArray():void {
//takes the properties defined in the XML and stores them 
//into arrays
var i:Number;
for (i = 0; i < listLength; i++) {
    imageArray[i]=xml.images[i].pic;

}

beginImage();
}

function beginImage():void {
//grabs a random number between 0 and the number
//of images in the array

//load description

var imageLoader = new Loader();

//catches errors if the loader cannot find the URL path
imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, catchFunction);
//actually loads the URL defined in the image array
imageLoader.load(new URLRequest(imageArray[currPainting]));
//adds a listener for while the image is loading
imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, imgLoading);
//adds a listener for what to do when the image is done loading
imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imgLoaded);


function catchFunction(e:IOErrorEvent) {
    trace("Bad URL: " + imageArray[currPainting] + " does not exist");
    //take out the bad URL from the array
    imageArray.splice(currPainting,1);
    //check to see if there are images left,
    //else restart the slideshow
    if (imageArray.length==0) {
        populateArray();
    } else {
        beginImage();
    }
}

function imgLoading(event:ProgressEvent):void{
    //show the loading bar, and update the width
    //based on how much is loaded
    loadingBar.visible = true;
    loadingBar.bar.scale = (event.bytesLoaded/event.bytesTotal)*100;
    loadingBar.x = stage.stageWidth/2;
    loadingBar.y = stage.stageHeight - 400;

}


var widthRatio:Number;
var heightRatio:Number;
function imgLoaded(event:Event):void {
    loadingBar.visible = false;

    //add the image and get the dimensions to center the image
    theImage.addChild(imageLoader);
    if (imageLoader.width > stage.stageWidth){
     widthRatio=imageLoader.width/stage.stageWidth;
     trace(widthRatio)
     trace(imageLoader.width);
        }
    if (imageLoader.height > stage.stageHeight - 207){
     heightRatio=imageLoader.height/(stage.stageHeight - 207) ;
     trace(heightRatio)
    trace(imageLoader.height)
    }

    if (widthRatio > heightRatio){
        imageLoader.width = stage.stageWidth;
        imageLoader.height = imageLoader.height/widthRatio;
    } else {
      imageLoader.height = stage.stageHeight - 207;
      imageLoader.width = imageLoader.width/heightRatio;
 }


    imageLoader.x = (imageLoader.stage.stageWidth / 2) - (imageLoader.width / 2);
    imageLoader.y = 0

    //take the contents of the loaded image and cast it as bitmap data
    //to allow for bitmap smoothing

    var image:Bitmap = imageLoader.content as Bitmap;
    image.smoothing=true;
    //start tween function
    easeIn();
}
}


function easeIn():void {

TweenLite.to(theImage, 5, {onComplete:hideStuff});
TweenLite.to(theImage, 1, {alpha:1, overwrite:0});
}

function hideStuff():void {
TweenLite.to(theImage, 1, {alpha:0, onComplete:nextImage});

}

function nextImage():void {
//take out the image that was just displayed
imageArray.splice(currPainting,1);


//remove the picture
theImage.removeChildAt(0);


//start over
if (imageArray.length==0) {
    populateArray();
} else {
    beginImage();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, first you need to create a variable for the image you wish to fade in. Let's organise it so it is clear which is which.

```
var theCurrentImage:DisplayObject;
var theNextImage:DisplayObject;
```

Load in the first image (now `theCurrentImage`) in the same way as before.

Now here's how you could load in the next image in the array:

```
function loadNextImage():void {
    currPainting++;
    // you should also make sure currPainting is not out of bounds here
    loadImage();
}

function loadImage():void {
    imageLoader = new Loader();
    imageLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onImageLoaded);
    // other listeners go here too
    imageLoader.load(new URLRequest(imageArray[currPainting]));
}

function onImageLoaded(e:Event):void {
    theNextImage = imageLoader; // stores the next image ready to be faded in
    theNextImage.alpha = 0;
    addChild(theNextImage); // now ready to be cross-faded in
    crossFade();
}

function crossFade():void {
    TweenLite.to(theCurrentImage, 1, {alpha:0});
    TweenLite.to(theNextImage, 1, {alpha:1});
    // remove theCurrentImage (now invisible) from the stage
    removeChild(theCurrentImage);
    // theNextImage is now the displayed image so...
    theCurrentImage = theNextImage;
    theNextImage = null;
    // ready to load the next image by calling loadNextImage()
}
```

Comment: this is not helping me :(

Comment: Why don't you tell me what part you don't understand and I'll explain it?

Comment: I dont understand it how to incorporate it into my code .. :( can you do this for me?

Comment: If you're struggling with this stuff, I would suggest taking a look at these tutorials [link](http://www.lynda.com). There's loads of stuff on Flash and more.

Comment: Thanks for this I already surf that but didnot find it better than stackoverflow